# How can I set up different footers for TableSections when using a Custom TableView Renderer

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am using a renderer to allow me to set a custom footer in my TableView. The renderer works but I would like to have the capability to set up different footers for the different table sections. For example one footer for table section 0 and another for table section 1, all the way up to table section 5.

Here's the XAML that I am using:

```
           <!-- <local:ExtFooterTableView x:Name="tableView" Intent="Settings" HasUnevenRows="True">-->
                <TableView x:Name="tableView" Intent="Settings" HasUnevenRows="True">
                <TableSection Title="Cards1">
                    <ViewCell Height="50">
                        <Label Text="Hello1" />
                    </ViewCell>
                    <ViewCell Height="50">
                        <Label Text="Hello2" />
                    </ViewCell>
                </TableSection>
                <TableSection Title="Cards2">
                    <TextCell Height="50" Text="Hello"></TextCell>
                </TableSection>

                </TableSection>
        <!--    </local:ExtFooterTableView>-->
            </TableView>
```

and here is the C# class and renderer:

```
public class ExtFooterTableView : TableView
{
    public ExtFooterTableView()
    {
    }
}
```

and:

```
   using System;
using Japanese;
using UIKit;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(ExtFooterTableView), typeof(Japanese.iOS.ExtFooterTableViewRenderer))]
namespace Japanese.iOS
{
    public class ExtFooterTableViewRenderer : TableViewRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<TableView> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);
            if (Control == null)
                return;

            var tableView = Control as UITableView;
            var formsTableView = Element as TableView;
            tableView.WeakDelegate = new CustomFooterTableViewModelRenderer(formsTableView);
        }


        private class CustomFooterTableViewModelRenderer : TableViewModelRenderer
        {
            public CustomFooterTableViewModelRenderer(TableView model) : base(model)
            {
            }

            public override UIView GetViewForFooter(UITableView tableView, nint section)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("xx");
                if (section == 0)
                {
                    return new UILabel()
                    {
                        // Text = TitleForFooter(tableView, section), // or use some other text here
                        Text = "abc",
                        TextAlignment = UITextAlignment.Left
                        // TextAlignment = NSTextAlignment.NSTextAlignmentJustified
                    };
                }
                else
                {
                    return new UILabel()
                    {
                        // Text = TitleForFooter(tableView, section), // or use some other text here
                        Text = "def",
                        TextAlignment = UITextAlignment.Left
                        // TextAlignment = NSTextAlignment.NSTextAlignmentJustified
                    };
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

The code works but I would like to find out how I can set up a different footer text for different sections in the XAML. Something like this:

From what I see it looks like the code is partly there `TitleForFooter(tableView, section)` but I am not sure how to use it and how I could set it up. Note that I am not really looking for a view model solution.  I would be happy to be simply able to specify the section footer text as part of the TableView XAML.

I'd appreciate if anyone could give me some advice on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, in order to be able to specify the section footer text in XAML - simplest option would be to create a bindable property in `TableSection`. But as `TableSection` is sealed, we can't derive it to define our custom bindable properties.

So, the next option is to create a attached bindable property.

```
public class Ex
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty FooterTextProperty =
        BindableProperty.CreateAttached("FooterText", typeof(string), typeof(Ex), defaultValue: default(string));

    public static string GetFooterText(BindableObject view)
    {
        return (string)view.GetValue(FooterTextProperty);
    }

    public static void SetFooterText(BindableObject view, string value)
    {
        view.SetValue(FooterTextProperty, value);
    }
}
```

Next step would be to update renderer to retrieve this value for every section:

```
private class CustomFooterTableViewModelRenderer : TableViewModelRenderer
{
    public CustomFooterTableViewModelRenderer(TableView model) : base(model)
    {
    }

    public override UIView GetViewForFooter(UITableView tableView, nint section)
    {
        return new UILabel()
        {
            Text = TitleForFooter(tableView, section), // or use some other text here
            Font = UIFont.SystemFontOfSize(14),
            ShadowColor = Color.White.ToUIColor(),
            ShadowOffset = new CoreGraphics.CGSize(0, 1),
            TextColor = Color.DarkGray.ToUIColor(),
            BackgroundColor = Color.Transparent.ToUIColor(),
            Opaque = false,
            TextAlignment = UITextAlignment.Center
        };
    }

    //Retrieves the footer text for corresponding section through the attached property
    public override string TitleForFooter(UITableView tableView, nint section)
    {
        var tblSection = View.Root[(int)section];
        return Ex.GetFooterText(tblSection);
    }
}
```

### Sample Usage

```
<local:ExtFooterTableView x:Name="tableView" Intent="Settings" HasUnevenRows="True">
    <TableSection Title="Cards1" local:Ex.FooterText="Sample description">
        <ViewCell Height="50">
            <Label Margin="20,0,20,0" Text="Hello1" />
        </ViewCell>
        <ViewCell Height="50">
            <Label Margin="20,0,20,0" Text="Hello2" />
        </ViewCell>
    </TableSection>
    <TableSection  Title="Cards2" local:Ex.FooterText="Disclaimer note">
        <TextCell Height="50" Text="Hello"></TextCell>
    </TableSection>
</local:ExtFooterTableView>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It is very simple. you need to add the bindable property for pass value from XAML to CustomRenderer in CustomControl like this:

#### Customer TableView

```
public class ExtFooterTableView : TableView
{
    public ExtFooterTableView()
    {
    }
}
```

#### Xaml control code

```
<local:ExtFooterTableView x:Name="tableView" Intent="Settings" HasUnevenRows="True">
```

#### Renderer class

```
using System;
using UIKit;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS;
using yournamespace;
using System.ComponentModel;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(ExtFooterTableView), typeof(FooterTableViewRenderer))]
namespace yournamespace
{
    public class FooterTableViewRenderer : TableViewRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<TableView> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);
        }


        protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, e);

            var view = (ExtFooterTableView)Element;

            if (e.PropertyName == ExtFooterTableView.IntentProperty.PropertyName)
            {
                string intent = view.Intent;
                // Do your stuff for intent property
            }

            if (e.PropertyName == ExtFooterTableView.HasUnevenRowsProperty.PropertyName)
            {
                bool hasUnevenRows = view.HasUnevenRows;
                // Do yout stuff for HasUnevenRow
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but how does this apply to the question where I was asking about Intent and HasUnevenRows.  Can you include a full answer if possible so I and others can see what's needed.

Comment: I tried this but it seems like as I inherit from TableView there's no need to add properties to the ExtFooterTableView as it already has them.  I've updated the question slightly as I notice that the problem is not so much with the height not being set but seems like there is a difference in the way ViewCell and TextCell are handled.  Maybe you can duplicate this. Thanks

Comment: Ok, I have removed this property, you asked the wrong question previously.

Comment: Yeah after I tried your solution I realized it was inherited and not needed.  Still wondering what's happening with the row height so left the question and just changed title as it's still a problem. Thanks